# Poner una imagen en un email

Tags: php, javascript, html5, email, phpmailer

Estoy intentando poner una imagen en un email. La imagen la tengo en un directorio y no la quiero subir a la nube por que se genera aleatoriamente. El email lo mando con phpMailer.
He probado de dos formas distintas, la primera es con  "$mail->addEmbeddedImage". Lo hago de esta forma:

```
 $mail->addEmbeddedImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/directorio/img/carlos/48/1.jpg", "prueba");
```

Donde primero pongo pongo la ruta y luego la sección debería salir la imagen.

La segunda forma es convirtiendo a base64 la imagen.

```
introducir el código aquí
$urlImagen = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/directorio/img/".$datosPalabras[6].".jpg"));
        $urlImagen = "data:image/jpeg;base64.$urlImagen";
```

Pero no consigo que la imagen salga en el email. Estoy utilizando para mandar el email mi cuenta de gmail. No creo que eso importe. Bueno a ver si alguien me ayuda con esto. Gracias

Comment: Si lo haces por base64 no tienes que concatenar la url de la imagen. Lo que tienes que concatenar es la imagen codificada en base64. En tu caso tienes algo asi: `data:image/jpeg;base64.locaholst/directorio/imagen.jpg` pero lo que tienes que generar es algo asi: `data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...` Ese ultimo galimatias es el resultado de codificar tu imagen en base64. Eso lo puedes hacer con la función `base64_encode`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php. En esa pagina hay un ejemplo en los comentarios si buscas por `base64_encode_image`.

Comment: Hola Ordago, gracias por responder. Lo hice como digiste y funciona perfecto.También solucione la otra forma de hacerlo. El problema era que no ponia el $cid en el html. Osea había que poner <img src='cid:prueba'> para saber donde incrustar la imagen.